# I haven't merged, but one of my commit says I did

Tags: git, github

Recently, I did only 1 commit but I don't know why it shows 3 commits.

Here is what I did recently:

1. Created a new repository on GitHub; initialized it with one `README` and `.gitignore` file. *(I understand GitHub commited on my behalf and so this is my first lost commit.)*
2. - `added` and `commited` a file.
   - did a `git remote add origin git@github.com:me/repo.git`
   - did `git pull origin master` to get the changes from the GitHub (README and .gitignore)
   - did `git push`

My questions are:

1. I haven't done anything like `git merge` then why my third commit says *"Merge branch 'master' of github.com:me/repo"*? What is going behind the curtain?
2. I had only expected the first two commits *(the one I did and the another which GitHub did when initialization of repo)*. Where did this 3rd came from? I can I get rid of these type of commits?

Any tips regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not have the merge commit when you do a pull, you want to do `git pull --rebase origin master`.  This will move the changes and not cause a merge.

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of [git pull](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

So, you actually *have* done a merge.

Comment: Was there any other way to do this? Any way to do without that 3rd commit?

Comment: I didn't wanted to merge, I just wanted to get the changes :/

Comment: To not have the merge commit when you do a pull you want to do "git pull --rebase origin master".  This will move you changes and not cause a merge.

Comment: wouldn't a "git fetch" just get the the changes?

Comment: `git fetch` would get the changes but would not incorporate them into your local branch (if you're on `master`, for example, `git fetch` would update `origin/master` but `master` would stay untouched and you would have to manually merge or rebase still to bring the remote commits into your local `master`. The approach @Schleis suggested is a good way to avoid a merge when pulling if the remote has new unpulled commits ahead of your local unpushed commits, as it will pull in the new remote commits and then rebase your local unpushed commits on top of them, avoiding the need for a merge.

Comment: @Schleis Can you please post your comment as an answer?